# Dismiss a view with swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my HomeViewController I have two segue, one is active when a cell is clicked and one when a bar button Item titeled `join list` is clicked. When the bar button item is clicked I want to check if the user is logged in or not. If the user is not logged in I want the LoginViewController interface to appear and if he is logged in I want the interface of joinViewController to appear. I created the join segue from the storyboard by holding ctrl from the join intem to the joinViewController and this is my code

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

       if segue.identifier == "detail" {
        var detailScene=segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
        if let indexPath=self.table.indexPathForSelectedRow{
            let selectedPerson=listPerson[indexPath.row]
            detailScene.person=selectedPerson
        }}

        else
        if segue.identifier == "join"{

            if !userLoggedIn{
                let vc : AnyObject! = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController")
                self.presentViewController(vc as! UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }

        }

        }
```

Everything is working fine but in the LoginViewController I added and IBAction to dismiss the view

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func dismissView(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

When the button is clicked the joinViewController is loaded instead of the homeViewControlled. Is what I did clean and how can I fix the dismiss button ?

Comment: You can try to override `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` in your `HomeViewController` and move the login logic in there. If not logged in return `false` otherwise `true`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically chose which `segue` to present, you should not set it up to the `UIBarButtonItem`. My suggestion is to drag two `segue` from `HomeViewController` to `LoginViewController` and `JoinViewController` with a name of `loginSegue` and `joinSegue`.

From the `UIBarButtonItem` create a `IBAction` to your `HomeViewController`. In the code it should look something like this:

```
@IBAction func barButtonItemPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
  if userLoggedIn {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("joinSegue", sender: self)
  } else {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSegue", sender: self)
  }
}
```

I am unsure about what you are asking about the dismiss button. But you cannot override `prepareForSegue` to select which `UIViewController` to present as at this stage, it is already going to present the `UIViewController`.